# Java not releasing objects with finalize() override

Tags: java, garbage-collection, finalizer

My application makes use of a third-party library (the JTDS driver) that has some objects that override the finalize() method.  I think they obey all the rules about when not to use `finalize()` - it doesn't depend on them running in a timely manner or at all.

The problem is that they objects are never being released.  They seem to get stuck in the Finalizer queue and never removed.  They build up slowly over a couple of weeks and run the JVM out of heap space.  Thread dumps show the Finalizer thread just waiting for something to call `finalize()` on.  If I call `System.runFinalization()`, the objects are finalized and are properly removed from the finalizer queue (and don't show up in heap dumps anymore).

Why will `System.runFinalization()` remove objects properly, but the Finalizer thread won't do it on its own?

Comment: I don't see how someone could reproduce your problem in order to help you.

Comment: What arguments are you passing to the JVM on start-up?

Comment: Unless you have the code of these finalize methods available, how do you expect someone to help exactly?

Comment: I really just wanted someone to comment on general Finalizer behavior, not necessarily to reproduce the issue.  Maybe someone has seen a similar issue with their classes (or in my case, third-party classes) that override finalize().

Comment: Describing finalizer behaviour is quite simple in fact: "unpredictable" ;) You should really report this bug to the library authors

Comment: Have same problem with finalizer thread waiting and finalisers causing OutOfMemory. The strangest thing is, this effect appears _randomly_ after each restart with _same_ jar. Could you find the solution?

Answer (score 1):

Had the same issue today. You are not specifying what JVM you are using but just in case it is OpenJDK - there is a bug https://lists.launchpad.net/openjdk/msg10021.html
They say it is already fixed so you just need to upgrade.

Answer (score 0):

This means your finalize() methods are taking too long resulting in objects building up in the queue waiting to be called.

Objects are removed from the queue as they are being called and wont be in the queue after being called.

Comment: but thread dumps show finalizer thread just waiting, not engaged in running one of the finalize methods? and on calling runFinalization it sounds like the finalizers all run in a timely fashion?

Comment: @GrahamGriffiths Most likely the problem is not what it appears to be.  Note: *after* all the objects have been finalized, the GC has to be called to clean them up.

Comment: Right, @GrahamGriffiths, the finalizer thread isn't doing anything at any time I can catch it in a thread dump.

Comment: @Jason The comment was meant for you.  DO you actually know the finializer queue is not empty after the finalizer thread has run?  Just having lots of finalizer node left doesn't mean any of these are still used.

Comment: @PeterLawrey, yes heap dumps generated on out-of-memory show that the finalizer queue is using nearly all of the memory with references to objects that override finalize().

Comment: @Jason In that case, your finalizer thread is unable to keep up with the amount of objects being discarded.

Comment: As mentioned, the finalizer thread isn't running a finalize() during any thread dump, the objects build up over a couple of weeks, and a call to System.runFinalization() will clean up the objects in less than a second.  That doesn't seem like the finalizer thread is unable to keep up with the objects being discarded.

Comment: @jason True, however you only need one long running Socket.close() or similar to lock up the finalizer thread.  I would check you are taking the stack trace at the right time.  BTW Are you using a recent version of Java?  If it is a bug in the JVM, it may have been fixed.

Answer (score 0):

> Why won't the Finalizer thread remove these objects?

The simple answer is, something in side the finalizer has caused a deadlock. Finalizers are the worst way to do clean-up. It is called by the garbage collector.

> Called by the garbage collector on an object when garbage collection
>   determines that there are no more references to the object.
>   What happens when the object to be garbage collector has a strong reference? The object never gets garbage collector. I strongly doubt this is what is happening in your case.

Joshua Bloch says in Effective Java:

> In summary don't use finalizers except as a safety net or to terminate
>   noncritical native resources

**Avoid finalizers - Finalizers are unpredictable, often dangerous, and generally unnecessary**

http://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=1216151&seqNum=7

Comment: The finalizer thread isn't deadlocked.  It's just waiting for something to do.  And the libraries authors do properly use the finalize() method as a "safety net or to terminate non-critical resources."  In fact, everything that the finalize() method is going to close has already been closed.  It's just the fact that the class overrides finalize() that causes it to be added to the finalizer queue.